# Error when installing gem 'ruby-debug-base' with ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have an error with RubyMine when I am trying to execute the debug-option.

```
Uncaught exception: Could not find gem 'ruby-debug-base (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine
```

The full stack trace is here

```
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17/bin/rdebug-ide --port 52748 --dispatcher-port 52749 -- script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17, debase 0.0.8) listens on 127.0.0.1:52748
Uncaught exception: Could not find gem 'ruby-debug-base (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:296:in `resolve'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:168:in `start'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:129:in `block in resolve'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `catch'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `resolve'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `resolve'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
    config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    /Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    script/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am using the following configuration

```
$ gem -v
2.0.3

$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.12

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]

$ gem list | grep debug
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.3)


$ gem install ruby-debug-base
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-base:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/linecache-0.46 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/linecache-0.46/ext/gem_make.out
```

I have been looking on google and all the fixes that I found it was for <2.0

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: if you can help me with this error.

Comment: You can do some more research before posting, never hurts!

Answer (score 1):

Use [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug).

The other gems mentioned here are either incompatible (`ruby-debug-base`), or broken (`debugger`) in `ruby v2.0`.